# Degradation Model in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying (using MATLAB) to generate the following image (from the section **4.1 Numerical Examples**) of Wu Tian Chen research article '[Condition-based Maintenance Optimization Using Neural Network-based Health Condition Prediction](http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~tian/index_files/Papers/QREI_Wu-Tian-Chen_2012.pdf)':

[image]

The model is derived from the equation:
$$
L(t)=θ′+β′t+ε(t)
$$
where $θ′$ is a normal random variable with mean $5$ and variance $1{^2}$, and $β′$ also be a normal random variable with mean $5$ and variance $1.5{^2}$. $ε(t)=σW(t)$ is a centered Brownian motion such that the mean of $ε(t)$ is zero and the variance of $ε(t)$ is  $σ{^2}t$.The parameters are set according to the article.

The MATLAB code I have written is the following:

```
% Initialization:
Ts          = 0;
Te          = 150;
Tn          = 101;
mu0         = 5;
sigma0      = 1;
mu1         = 5;
sigma1      = 1.5;
sigma       = .5;
D           = 500; % failure threshold
paths = 50; % Number of paths in accordance with the article and graph

figure, hold on, box on, grid off

t = linspace(Ts, Te, Tn)';

for i = 1:paths 
   % Generate θ':
    teta1 = randn() * sigma0 + mu0;
   % Generate β':
    beta1 = (randn() * sigma1 + mu1) .* t;

   % Generate Brownian path
    dW = sqrt(Te / Tn) * randn(Tn, 1);
    W = cumsum(dW, 1); % cumulative sum
    e_t = sigma * W;

   L = teta1 + beta1 + e_t;   
   plot(t, L);
   xlim([Ts, Te])
   ylim([0, 600])

end

% Draws threshold
plot([Ts, Te], [D, D], 'k', 'LineWidth', 2.5)

title('Degradation Signal', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'FontSize', 14);
xlabel('Time (day)', 'FontSize', 12);
ylabel('Amplitude', 'FontSize', 12);
```

The output of this code is different from the original one, but I don't understand why. In have already applied the changes from A. Donda, but the plot is still different, due to the abscence of fluctuations.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code for the linear part is wrong. As far as I understand, $\theta'$ and $\beta'$ vary randomly over instantiations, but are constant over time. To implement this, you have to write

```
% Generate θ':
theta1 = randn() * sigma0 + mu0;
% Generate β':
beta1 = (randn() * sigma1 + mu1) .* t;
```

Secondly, there are several strange things in your code to generate a Brownian path: There's an $\exp()$ without motivation, you use the constant `0.5` instead of the defined parameter `sigma`, and you have an additional factor 0.5 in the code for `dW`. IMHO, that section should look like this:

```
dW = sqrt(Te / Tn) * randn(Tn, 1);
W = cumsum(dW);
e_t = sigma * W;
```

There'd be also a problem here if `Ts` is not zero, so I'd recommend to just remove that parameter and replace it by 0 everywhere.

With this modified code, the result looks like this:

[image]

which is still not what you aim at. However, I think the parameters you use are not consistent with your plot anyway. For one, if the variance of $\beta'$ is supposed to be 1.5, then you have to write

```
sigma1 = sqrt(1.5);
```

since $\sigma_1$ is the standard deviation. Moreover, if $\sigma = 0.5$ for the Brownian motion, then the variance of $\epsilon(150)$ is 37.5, and the standard deviation 6.12. The fluctuations in your plot however are quite a bit larger.

Hope this helps.